# Excel VBA reference for Inet objects

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

Excel VBA code is failing to compile on this Dim statement:

> Dim FTP as Inet

Apparently, others have solved this problem by including a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls, which I have done.  This reference is pointing to:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ieframe.dll

Thinking that the dll might not be registered, I ran

> regsvr32 ieframe.dll

with administrative privileges but got an error message that the module was loaded but "the call to DllRegisterServer failed", which might be a separate issue.

Is this the right reference to use for Inet objects?  If so, what should I do to compile this code?

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863449/vba-excel-and-ftp-with-msinet-ocx-and-inet-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The INet object is a member of the Microsoft Internet Transfer Control 6.0 (SP6), NOT Microsoft Internet Controls. [INet Reference](http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/ftp_download_file.html).  The correct control can be found in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msinet.ocx.  You will likely have to change the "Files of type" box to "ActiveX Controls (*.oxc)" in the references window.

Comment: Yes, many thanks. The comment to the OP by rskar led me to figure this out. Browsing for MSINET.OCX in the VBA editor found this reference and the code compiles now.