# Connecting to FTP from Excel to automate file sharing (VBA Beginner)

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

I'm a beginner and new to Excel VBA, but I'm trying to automate some file sharing in FTP (WinSCP) by connecting to Excel and maybe creating a macro that will help. In FTP I went to Session > Generate Session URL/code > Script (script file) and the following code is there:

```
open ftp://myUsername:myPassword@theHostname/

# Your command 1
# Your command 2

exit
```

I'm assuming the open line would connect Excel to FTP. I'm referencing code from this site to put into the '# command' area: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/261043-connecting-ftp-excel.html

```
open ftp://myUsername:myPassword@theHostname/

Option Explicit

Sub FtpTest()
    MsgBox fnDownloadFile("ftp://yoursite", "username", "password", _
        "The name of your file", _
        "C:\The name of your file to save as")
End Sub

Function fnDownloadFile(ByVal strHostName As String, _
    ByVal strUserName As String, _
    ByVal strPassWord As String, _
    ByVal strRemoteFileName As String, _
    ByVal strLocalFileName As String) As String

    '// Set a reference to: Microsoft Internet Transfer Control
    '// This is the Msinet.ocx

    Dim FTP As Inet    'As InetCtlsObjects.Inet

    Set FTP = New Inet 'InetCtlsObjects.Inet

    On Error GoTo Errh
    With FTP
        .URL = strHostName
        .Protocol = 2
        .UserName = strUserName
        .Password = strPassWord
        .Execute , "Get " + strRemoteFileName + " " + strLocalFileName
        Do While .StillExecuting
            DoEvents
        Loop
        fnDownloadFile = .ResponseInfo
    End With
Xit:
    Set FTP = Nothing
    Exit Function

Errh:
    fnDownloadFile = "Error:-" & Err.Description
    Resume Xit
End Function

exit
```

I did as this site said to go to VBA Editor > Tools > reference and check off Microsoft Internet Control.

1) Am I using the code right? Did I place it in the right area (in the '# command' area)? And right now I put the entire code in a Command Button, but when I click it it just gives me a Syntax Error highlighting the first line:
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click())

2) Do I leave the Msgbox on the 3rd line as is to wait for user input or do I fill out with my username/password/hostname? (I'm not very good with functions in VBA yet) If I do fill it out in the code, what do I put for the "yoursite" value since I'm not accessing a website?

I'm sorry I'm so confused :( Any help would be great and thank you in advance!

Comment: You are mixing two completely different approaches together. WinSCP is a scriptable FTP client, that you can indeed run from your VBA. Or you can use the `InetCtlsObjects.Inet`. But do not use both.

Comment: I see that's in comments next to Dim FTP As Inet and Set FTP = New Inet - do those lines do the same thing? And do you mean I should get rid of the first 'open ftp..' line?

Comment: No they do not do the same. The first declares a variable, while the second assigns a new instance of class to the variable + Yes, remove the `open`, that's not VB, that's WinSCP scripting command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that You should take a look here - [Excel VBA reference for Inet objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756740/excel-vba-reference-for-inet-objects)
it is shown here how to add refernce for INet objects in vba. Furthermore when You just want to test if the code works, instead of assigning macro to button and so on, if You use "Function" then when You go to worksheet cell and start to type =fnDown ... You should see Your macro - there You can put Your function parameters. However first of all You have to take care of the reference to Inet.

This link might also be helpful: [VBA Excel and FTP with MSINET.OCX and Inet type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863449/vba-excel-and-ftp-with-msinet-ocx-and-inet-type)

Comment: Thanks for the references - I can't seem to find the msinet.ocx anywhere in C:\Windows though

Comment: Indeed, it is hard to find this reference as I saw that it was present in Win XP... however, I've found another interesting source. https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23627204/Download-file-from-remote-ftp-site-via-VBA-Excel.html                  Furthermore, it depends what You want to do with this FTP, but e. g. You can use webbrowser control in Excel and it will emulate the WebBrowser - You will be able to manipulate the site.

Comment: I got the reference to msinet.ocx and MS Internet Transfer successfully, but can you explain more how you test and where to place the code?

Comment: Hi, great. So in Your workbook alt+f11 then on the left side bar right click and add new module. To this module at the top add "Option Explicit" to force Your code to be without errors before compile. Then paste below Your code that starts with Function. When You do that then in a worksheet You can use this function as formula - start typing in any cell  =NameOfYourFunction nad put inside it parameters which are required, e. G. Ftp address. So that You will be able to check it Code works. If not then go to vba editor and left click in the left bar at the level of the first line of Function

Comment: ... Code then the debbuger will stop at this point when the function fires  (when You put it in the worksheet cell) nad You will be able to debug with F8 line by line to check nie Code works.

Comment: If everyrhing works then I recommend to add user form. 1. In vba editor right click in the left side bar and choose add new user form. In this form You should add some e. G. textboxes in which user will type parameters like ftp address and ok button od submit button. Then in Your module add the Sub MyFtp() (You can name it as You want). This sub will be assigned to button in a tab. And this sub will show user form, get data from it and transfer this parametrs to Your ftp function. (To my knowledge message box cannot get so many parametrs as You require so it is better to use user form).

Comment: On the other hand if You want your macro to perform the same operation all the time  (with constant parametrs) then into module paste Your Function . Then Function(...) replace with Sub ftp () and parametrs from brackets put below Sub ftp () line. You will have to replace ByVal with Dim

Comment: Dim strHostName As String
    Dim strUserName As String
    Dim strPassWord As String
    Dim strRemoteFileName As String
    Dim strLocalFileName As String       and then below put parametrs e. G. strUserName = "admin" and so on

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm getting an error when I try to add =fnDownloadFile to a cell in Excel though - I entered =fnDownloadFile(Hostname, Username, Password) but I'm not sure what values to put into Remote and Local file names. Is local just the file name of a file I want to drop into FTP? I created a test .txt file for this. But what is the Remote file supposed to be?

Comment: So according to Your function I think that You need 5 parameters which are strings. It should look like =fnDonwloadFile("ftp://yoursite"; "username"; "password"; "The name of your file"; "C:\The name of your file to save as in fact path"). In my excel the separator between parameters is ; but in Your case it might be different.

Comment: Thanks, the quotes and file path were all I needed! I kept getting a Syntax error whenever I entered in the code in a cell highlighting the function parameters area, so I used this code instead: http://officeoneonline.com/vba/ftp_download_file.html (they had different functions for uploading and downloading a file, so I put each in a different  Module and called the =fnNames in 2 different cells. When I press Enter after typing in the function, I get TRUE in the cell but nothing really happens to my test files (I have 2 test .txt's - C:\My Docs\Remote and C:\My Docs\Local)

Comment: In fact these two functions can be placed in the same module. However, one should be named e. g. fun1 and second fun2. They cannot have the same name. So if the function return true but nothing happens then You should debug step by step to see what actually happens.  (here is article about debbuging in vba: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)

Comment: Thanks for all the help!