# regsvr32 msinet.ocx Error

Tags: vba, excel, ftp, regsvr32

(Trying to solve my ultimate goal- [Connecting to FTP from Excel to automate file sharing (VBA Beginner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781828/connecting-to-ftp-from-excel-to-automate-file-sharing-vba-beginner))

I'm trying to add Microsoft Internet Transfer Control but it doesn't show up in Excel VBA when I go to Tools>Reference so I followed [this](http://officeoneonline.com/vba/ftp_download_file.html) site.

msinet.ocx was not in my system32 or SysWOW64 folder so I think I'm supposed to install it at command line so I initially tried running regsvr32 msinet.ocx at C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and I get the same error for both: "The module msinet.ocx failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .dll files. The specified module could not be found."

Then I tried running cmd.exe as an administrator and trying it again in both System32 and SysWOW64 and I still get the same error popup. I don't know what to try now. Do I need to do a System Restore? And is that a safe thing to do on my work laptop?

P.S. I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally through this link - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ee5696aa-c94d-481a-bbbe-4dad30ccae7f/vista-error-message-msinetocx-not-correctly-registeredfile-is-missing-or-invalid?forum=itprovistaact

Using Peter's and BVBravo's posts

Comment: I don't have VB installed and wont be able to. I tried the BVBravo's solution but didn't work for me. I keep getting the same error. Is there any recommended website from where we have to download MSINET.ocx and install ir using regsvr32.exe. FYI my machine configuration is Windows 10 64 bit, Office 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You properbly need to run the CMD as administrator to get your regsrv32 to work.

I had the same problem in windows 2012 server and it only works when you run the CMD as administrator and then type the regsrv32 "C:\Windows\sysWoW64\msinet.ocx"